# Draw rectangle inside an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to draw a draggable and resizable rectangle/box on an IFrame instead of Canvas or div, How can i go with this?
Currently i am working with the jsFiddle example below with link
[I used this Js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XELRX/1/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    var welcome_area = $('.inner_col_two'),
        main_content = $('.col_two'),
        css_module = $('.inner_col_one'),
        gen_box = null,
        i  = 1;

    //fade out welcome button and remove it
    $('.start-button').click(function() {
        welcome_area.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            //when welcome button is removed fade in the css module and make .col_two selectable
            //css_module.fadeIn('slow').resizable().draggable();
        }); //end start button fade callback function
    });//end start button click
    
    //make .col_two selectable and...
    main_content.selectable({ 
                start: function(e) {
                        
                        //get the mouse position on start
                        x_begin = e.pageX,
                        y_begin = e.pageY;

                    },
                stop: function(e) {
                        
                        //get the mouse position on stop
                        x_end = e.pageX,
                        y_end = e.pageY;

                        /***  if dragging mouse to the right direction, calcuate width/height  ***/

                        if( x_end - x_begin >= 1 ) {
                            width  = x_end - x_begin,
                            height = y_end - y_begin;
                        
                        /***  if dragging mouse to the left direction, calcuate width/height (only change is x) ***/
                        
                        } else {
                            
                            width  = x_begin - x_end,
                            height =  y_end - y_begin;
                            var drag_left = true;
                        }
                        
                        //append a new div and increment the class and turn it into jquery selector
                        $(this).append('<div class="gen_box_' + i + '"></div>');
                        gen_box = $('.gen_box_' + i);

                        //add css to generated div and make it resizable & draggable
                        $(gen_box).css({
                            'background' : '#fff',
                             'width'     : width,
                             'height'    : height,
                             'position'  : 'absolute',
                             'left'      : x_begin,
                             'top'         : y_begin
                        })
                        .draggable({ grid: [20, 20] })
                        .resizable({
         stop: function(event, ui) {
          var secondwidth = ui.size.width;
          alert('Resized width: '+secondwidth);
          var secondheight = ui.size.height;
            alert('Resized Height: '+secondheight);
         }
      });
      var  current_box_width = width;
      alert('Box width = '+current_box_width);
      var  current_box_height = height;
      alert('Box height = '+current_box_height); 
      var x = $(gen_box).position();
            alert("Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left);
                        //if the mouse was dragged left, offset the gen_box position 
                        drag_left ? $(gen_box).offset({ left: x_end, top: y_begin }) : false;
                        console.log( 'width: ' + width + 'px');
                        console.log( 'height: ' + height + 'px' );
                        //add thr styles of generated div into .inner_col_one
                        i++;
                }});
});
```

```css
 html {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
  }
  body {
      background:#ccc;
      height:101%;
      width:101%;
  }
  h3 {
      font:bold 20px georgia, serif;
  }  
  #wrapper {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0 auto;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  /* --------- col_one elements(stylesheet) --------- */
  
  .col_one {
      height:100%;
      width:18%;
      background:#ffe3ac;
      min-width:1px;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0px;
      right:0px;
  }
  .inner_col_one {
      margin:10px;
      padding:20px;
      min-height:200px;
      background:white;
      -webkit-border-radius:10px;
      -moz-border-radius:10px;
      border-radius:10px;
      -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
      -moz-box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
      box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  .button.dl-css {
      float:left;
      margin:0 auto;
      display:block;
  }
  /* --------- col_two elements(Create divs) --------- */
  
  .col_two {
      background:#ffe3ac;
      float:left;
      height:100%;
   position;
  relative;
      width:100%;
  }
  .inner_col_two {
      border:1px dashed black;
      width:40%;
      margin:13% auto;
      text-align:center;
      background:white;
      -webkit-border-radius:10px;
      -moz-border-radius:10px;
      border-radius:10px;
      -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
      -moz-box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
      box-shadow:0 0 7px -1px #999;
  }
  /* ------------ generic styles ------------ */
  
  .full-width {
      width:100%;
  }
   /* box styles */
  
  .ui-resizable {
      -webkit-border-radius:10px;
      -moz-border-radius:10px;
      border-radius:10px;
  }
  .ui-resizable.ui-resizable-resizing, .ui-resizable.ui-draggable-dragging {
      border:2px dashed #ffcc66 !important;
  }
  .selected {
      background:#ffffff;
  }
  /* prettify styles */
  .prettyprint {
      border:none !important;
      font: 16px 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  }
  /* generated content */
  #canvas {
      height: 500px;
      background: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/188.0.0/prettify.js"></script>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col_one css">
      <div class="inner_col_one"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_two">
      <!--<div class="inner_col_two">
        <input type="button" value="Create a div" class="start-button"/>
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you're using? It seems to work well in the fiddle example.

Comment: I want to apply this fiddle on an Iframe, is it possible to draw a rectangle on an iframe?  thanks for reply Rory Mc Crossan